# Force throwing of exception when a source property is unmapped

Tags: c#, automapper

In AutoMapper 2.2.1, is there any way I can configure my mappings so that when a property is not explicitly ignored, an exception is thrown? For example, I have the following classes and configuration:

```
public class Source
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}


// Config
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

The behavior I receive with this configuration is that the `Destination.X` and `Destination.Y` properties are set. Furthermore, if I test my configuration:

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Then I will receive no mapping exceptions. What I would like to happen is that an `AutoMapperConfigurationException` is thrown because `Source.Z` is not explicitly ignored.

I would like it so that I have to explicitly ignore the Z property in order for `AssertConfiguartionIsValid` to run without exceptions:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForSourceMember(m => m.Z, e => e.Ignore());
```

Currently, AutoMapper **does not** throw an exception. I would like it to throw an exception if I do not explicitly specify the `Ignore`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is method which asserts that all source type properties are mapped:

```
public static void AssertAllSourcePropertiesMapped()
{
    foreach (var map in Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps())
    {
        // Here is hack, because source member mappings are not exposed
        Type t = typeof(TypeMap);
        var configs = t.GetField("_sourceMemberConfigs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var mappedSourceProperties = ((IEnumerable<SourceMemberConfig>)configs.GetValue(map)).Select(m => m.SourceMember);

        var mappedProperties = map.GetPropertyMaps().Select(m => m.SourceMember)
                                  .Concat(mappedSourceProperties);

        var properties = map.SourceType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (!mappedProperties.Contains(propertyInfo))
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Property '{0}' of type '{1}' is not mapped", 
                                                  propertyInfo, map.SourceType));
        }
    }
}
```

It checks all configured mappings and verifies that each source type property has mapping defined (either mapped, or ignored).

Usage:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
// ...
AssertAllSourcePropertiesMapped();
```

That throws exception

> Property 'Int32 Z' of type 'YourNamespace.Source' is not mapped

If you will ignore that property, all is fine:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .ForSourceMember(s => s.Z, opt => opt.Ignore());
AssertAllSourcePropertiesMapped();
```

Comment: It's a shame that the source member mappings are not exposed on `TypeMap`.

Comment: @MikeBantegui completely agree with you. In first edit of answer I simply used `GetPropertyMaps()` but it was surprise for me that neither source mappings were here, nor source mappings were exposed as public property of TypeMap

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of AutoMapper have the `MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` method that verifies that all properties are mapped.