# Mapping inherited type returns null when base class is abstract

Tags: c#, inheritance, automapper

I'm using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map some inherited classes in C#. Let's say I have the following classes (properties omitted):

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Bird : Animal {}

abstract class Animal2 {}
class Bird2 : Animal2 {}
```

And this AutoMapper configuration.

```
...
cfg.CreateMap<Animal, Animal2>()
   .Include<Bird, Bird2>();

cfg.CreateMap<Bird, Bird2>(); // This seems a bit repetitive?
...
```

This maps to the sub-type, which is all great.

```
Animal source = new Bird();
var result = mapper.Map<Animal2>(source);
result.Should().BeOfType<Bird2>(); // Yay
```

**But**, what if I add a new sub-type and forget to configure a mapping for it (which is pretty much guaranteed to happen over the lifetime of the application)?

```
class Fish : Animal {}
...
Animal source = new Fish();
var result = mapper.Map<Animal2>(source);
// Argh, result is null!
```

In this case, AutoMapper quietly returns a `null` value, which could cause an application to fail quite ungracefully.

**Can AutoMapper be configured to throw a meaningful exception in this case?** (As it does when not using inherited types).

Or do I just have to wrap all `Map()` calls in my own method to check for `null`s?

## Update

This is **not a duplicate** of [Force throwing of exception when a source property is unmapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409871/force-throwing-of-exception-when-a-source-property-is-unmapped)
. That question refers to unmapped *properties*, my question is about unmapped *types*. The suggested code in the answer doesn't help here.

## Update 2

It's also not a duplicate of [Is AutoMapper AssertConfigurationIsValid enough to ensure good mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037986). The [AutoMapper docs on configuration validation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) say:

> AutoMapper checks to make sure that every single Destination type member has a corresponding type member on the source type.

So this is checking that existing type mappings are valid, not that a type mapping exists in the first place.

I don't think my issue (the lack of a mapped destination type for an inherited type) can be detected by static analysis. But, I think it would be better (and more consistent) for AutoMapper to throw an exception at runtime when I attempt to map this inherited type, instead of returning `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Erik. As I've explained in the update, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is AutoMapper AssertConfigurationIsValid enough to ensure good mapping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037986/is-automapper-assertconfigurationisvalid-enough-to-ensure-good-mapping)